# firefox version 23 problem

Tags: 12.04, firefox

When I start Firefox on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I get this prompt:

```
could not initialize the program's security component ...
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled but to no effect.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following:

1. `sudo apt-get purge firefox`

   - This will completely remove Firefox.
2. `cd ~ && rm -r .mozilla`

   - This will remove a folder that Firefox might leave behind.
3. `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get install firefox`

   - This will redownload and install Firefox.

Once the last step is done, try opening up Firefox and check if it works.

**Source: [Ubuntu Forums: Firefox - Could not initialize applicaiton security component](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=904772)**